# How do I get our website to load under 1 second?

Tags: html, css, responsive, performance

We have a responsive business website running in html5. Our goal always has been to load the site up fast so the users can browse and get the required info even if they are in a slow bandwidth area. Since our users are from every part of the world and the internet connection is not up to speed in every country, the best option we have is to deliver the content as fast as possible. The main purpose is to have the homepage optimized for speed and the rest of the pages can be served quickly from cache. The steps so far taken:

1. main document - 10 kb
2. fonts are preloaded in head
3. reduced and minified css - final size 6kb
4. use cdn for jquery.slim.min.js - size 25kb
5. main image compressed and reduced from 600kb to webp- final size 20kb
6. favicon - final size 940 bytes
7. use cdn for bootstrap js async loaded- size 23kb
8. font reduced - final size 20kb
9. font awesome locally served - final size 1kb
10. analytics (preconnected as well) including googletag async loaded - 50kb
11. .htaccess edited for browser caching (images,css,js,ico,webp,jpg etc) for repeat visits.

Having done all of that, the site loading really gotten faster and the consistent results for lighthouse are provided below for desktop and mobile respectively:

[image: Desktop results]

[image: Mobile results]

gtmetrix, pingdom has the site loading in 1-1.2 seconds consistently. Domcontentloaded - 910ms. The results are pretty similar from different regions in the world (tested from 8 different countries). Our site is hosted in hostgator and they are gzipping content. Above sizes are for the files that are compressed and sent to browsers before deflating. I have been studying all over the web including stackoverflow to see what can be optimized (for first visit) to get to that sweet spot. I even minified the html which negatively affected the performance, so it is put back to original. homepage html file doesnt have any comments so valuable bytes are not wasted and also we dont have any videos. What else can be done to shave off 200-300 milliseconds ? :) Appreciate any valuable info/advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WOW!! Great job you are doing, I think you might only add one thing to make it faster which is using some lazyloading for content and photos if any, and fetch them whenever they are in the view port.

Comment: Great suggestion. We dont have any photos currently but will implement that in future if added :)